# How do Qatar-Indigo codeshare flights work?

Tags: layovers, connecting-flights, qatar-airways, code-share, indigo

I have a ticket booked with Qatar Airways flight codes from Delhi to Doha and then from Doha to Amsterdam. I have booked my tickets through a third-party vendor, and both tickets indicate that the flight is with Qatar Airways. After doing some research, I found out that the flight from Delhi to Doha will be operated by Indigo. How does this work in codeshare flights? Do I need to check-in again in Doha for the Qatar flight? Will I receive my checked baggage in Doha or will it be directly sent to Amsterdam?

The flight numbers are QR 4771 from Delhi to Doha and QR 273 from Doha to Amsterdam.

Comment: You say "the tickets", but are the two flights really on separate tickets or on a single ticket? You should have a single ticket number (a long 13-digit number starting with 157 in theory) and a single PNR/booking reference.

Comment: please share how was your experience ? did you get both boarding passes at mumbai ? did you get your luggage checked in from mumbai to final destination? or you have to take luggage in DOHA and check in again for final destination?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know the specifics in this particular case, but the whole goal of codeshare flights is that for the passenger, it is exactly as if the flight was operated by the codeshare airline.

So codeshare agreements normally include the ability to do through check-in, to transfer luggage from one flight to the next, and so on (what is called an "interlining agreement").

As long as the two flights are booked on a single ticket/PNR, you should be able to:

- perform "through check-in" in Delhi: luggage will be tagged directly with the final destination, and you should get boarding passes for both flights
- get your luggage automatically transferred from one flight to the other so you don't see it in Doha, and it gets delivered in Amsterdam.

The situation is different if the two flights are booked separately. In this case, unless you manage get the flights joined together, you would have to go through immigration, reclaim your bags, go to departures, check-in for the second flight (before the check-in deadline), go through exit checks.

Comment: Yes it's a single ticket/PNR

Answer (score 3):

For anyone searching for answers about a flight from DEL - Europe, Layover in Doha, The below applies to the first leg (DEL-DOH) operated by Indigo

1. The check-in has to be done at the Airport
2. Meal selection is purely dependent on availability in flight

   1. There is no way to pre-select from any website
   2. Even the support agents on Indigo cannot select it
   3. So if you are served late, you might be out of options, especially if you are vegetarian
3. The support agents on Indigo can select the seat for you

   1. The agent I chatted to was able to allocate me 13F (inarguably one of the best seats).
   2. They did it without any extra charge. Usually, exit row seats with extra legroom cost quite a bit extra.

Answer (score 0):

I had a flight from Vienna to New Delhi with a stop over at Istanbul. This was Turkish Airlines and Indigo.
Tomorrow, I will have the flight from New Delhi to Vienna with a stop over at Doha. This is Indigo and Qatar.

I would suggest to not to go with code sharing flights for the following reason.

Web check-in is a issue here.
In case of Turkish and Indigo, I could not do web check-in in either of the flights. I checked in at the counter and was given the last seat which is not a good seat.

In case Indigo and Qatar, I could only select seats in Qatar but no web check-in in either of the flights.